# Display name of object on GUI box

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, mouseover

I've create 2 cubes (cube 1, cube 2). When I mouse over on either cube 1 or cube 2 I want to display its name in a GUI box. The name displays in the console but not in my GUI box using the following code:

```
Public class Label : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public string collidedmesh;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        collidedmesh=transform.name;
        Debug.Log("........"+collidedmesh);
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(300, 100, 100, 20),""+collidedmesh);   
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        OnGUI();
    }
}
```

Output is

[image]

Comment: What is _not working_ exactly?

Comment: Do you see the box on your screen? Why are you adding the name to an empty string?

Comment: yes but cube 1 and cube 2  prints on same box... can u give the idea...

Comment: Maybe it's a problem in the layout file. Maybe they are on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

You're rendering all of your boxes in the same location. Use a relative position by referencing `transform.position` and passing it through `Camera.WorldToScreenPoint()` to get it in [screen-space](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html).

```
void OnGUI()
{
    Vector3 screenCoord = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    GUI.Box(new Rect(screenCoord.x, screenCoord.y, 100, 20),collidedmesh);
}
```

Additionally doing `"" + collidedmesh` is a wasted operation, just use collidedmesh instead.

Comment: public class Raycast : MonoBehaviour {

 public string collidedmesh;
 
 
 void OnGUI()
 {
  Vector3 screenCoord = Camera.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
  GUI.Box(new Rect(screenCoord.x, screenCoord.y, 100, 20),collidedmesh);
 }
 }                                                                       When i drag this code in to cube1 and cube 2 , error like         "An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.Camera.WorldToScreenPoint(UnityEngine.Vector3)'"

Comment: When I mouse over on either cube 1 or cube 2 I want to display its name in a GUI box. but in this code where u use mouse over condition/function.

Comment: This code is to be added to your code. Simply replace the ONGUI function with my version.

Comment: You're setting collidedmesh at start, which runs for each object you attach Label component to. Instead you should set it in OnMouseDown and only render the box when collidedmesh isn't an empty string. You should also clear collidedmesh when the mouse is no longer over it.

Comment: sorry i couldnt make it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to display the name of the box when you hover it, or when you click on it?

Your issue are twofold:

-OnGUI is called automatically, so you can't call it like that; it's happening regardless

-You are using OnMouseDown, which only gets called when you effectively click on the object

So fix to them, remove the OnMouseDown() function.
Add a boolean to the top of your code, such as

```
bools isHovering = false;
```

Then, in your OnGUI() function, add an if statement before the GUI.Box, like so:

```
if(isHovering)
{
    GUI.Box(new Rect(300, 100, 100, 20),""+collidedmesh);
}
```

Finally, add both a OnMouseEnter() and a OnMouseExit(), which will set the bool value depending on whether the mouse is hovering over your object or not, like this:

```
void OnMouseEnter()
{
    isHovering = true;
}

void OnMouseExit()
{
    isHovering = false;
}
```

This way, when you hover over something, the bool is set to true, activating the GUI.Box that shows the object name. When you stop hovering over it, the bool is set to false, deactivating the GUI.Box. Good luck.